# I need to compare 2 strings using a For loop in c#

Tags: c#, string, compare

I need to compare 2 strings using a For without using String.compare. (It's a homework ... I started programming C# 2 weeks ago)

I just can't figure out how to use the for loop to answer the question. I don't know what to put in for(). I tried `for( string text1 = "something",)` but I can't figure out what toput after the, in the for loop.

Comment: OK, thanks for being up-front about it being homework. Have you made any attempts at solving this on your own, is there a particular part you are struggling with? If so, can you please update and share that information? What should the *result* of the comparison be, just a simple true / false for if they are equal? The index which the strings start to differ?

Comment: I just can't figure out how to use the for loop to answer the question.  I don't know what to put in for(). I tried for( string text1 = "something",) but I can't figure out what toput after the , in the for loop.

Comment: A true if they are equal would be great. But I don't understand how to use the for loop to get a bool by comparing 2 strings.

Comment: Hint: make a for loop that compares one character at a time.

Comment: @Mthb54 if the answer provided solved your problem, please accept it to give the helper credit :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Since this is a homework question, I would recommend stop reading the answer as soon as you think you have enough information to solve it on your own before getting to the solution at the end.*

Let's assume a simple method signature, first:

```
public static bool AreStringEqual(string str1, string str2)
{
}
```

And our goal is to implement (write the code for) this method. We'll assume our goal is *Return true if the strings are equal, and return false if they are not*. We won't do anything fancy like make it case insensitive.

We can do some basic checks on our strings, first. If they are of different length, then we can immediately assume the strings are different, and return false:

```
if (str1.Length != str2.Length)
{
    return false;
}
```

This block checks the length, and if they differ, then false is immediately returned and the rest of the method doesn't get executed.

At this point we can guarantee the strings are the same length, so we can loop over the strings and compare them character by character using a `for` loop.

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < str1.Length; counter++)
{
}
```

This is a pretty standard for-loop that just counts a number from zero to one less than the length of the string. It doesn't matter if we use `str1` or `str2` for the upper bound of the loop since we already know they are the same length.

To get the character in a string, we can use the [Indexer Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx) to get the character at a give position. The numbers start at zero in C# and .NET.

`str1[0]` gets the first character, `str1[1]` gets the second, etc.

We can then plug the variable in the for loop into the indexer for `str1` and `str2`, then compare the characters. If they are not equal, then return false.

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < str1.Length; counter++)
{
    if (str1[counter] != str2[counter])
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And finally, if the code gets through the for loop without returning false, then return true at the end. Putting it all together, it looks like this:

```
public static bool AreStringEqual(string str1, string str2)
{
    if (str1.Length != str2.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for(int counter = 0; counter < str1.Length; counter++)
    {
        if (str1[counter] != str2[counter])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Note to others: I am well aware I can use `var` and other things. The goal here is to show exactly what is going on and be explicit as possible, not go for what is the most attractive looking code.

Comment: I like the answer by @vcsjones, but strictly speaking you should also make sure that your string arguments are non-null before attempting to access their Length properties.

Comment: @Lorek you're right from a best practices point of view, but it isn't part of what is trying to be explained here. That's left as an exercise to the OP. This question was specifically about looping, not writing an efficient, error free string comparison. For all I know the concept of nulls, references, and exceptions hasn't been taught yet.